# Python selenium-не видит элемент на новой вкладке

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему выдает ошибку? Элемент находится на другом окне и xpath правильный. На сайте находится 2 html.
сайт:avizo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716311/12605749

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно переключаться каждый раз на нужную вами вкладку, либо же работать только в с одной вкладкой. В таком случае не нужно переключаться.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```